# SQL: Get date from table

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have a column which stores datetime like 2011-01-01 01:01:01 .

I need to get list of date:

```
2011-01-01
2011-02-01
```

Is there any way I can list down date from datetime in a table?

Answer (score 2):

If the column is really a datetime, just use the `date()` function:

```
select date(column)
from table t;
```

Actually, this also works if the column is a string, assuming it is in YYYY-MM-DD format.

If you want a unique list of dates:

```
select distinct date(column)
from table t;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select substr(field,1,10)
```

For just a list of the dates.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(field, '%Y-%m-%d')
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQL**

```
select to_char(date_column,'YYYY-MM-DD') from table;
```

**MySql**

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(date_column,'%Y-%m-%d') from table;
```

You can use [`DATE_FORMAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

Syntax:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2011-10-10 19:46:00', '%M %d, %Y');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```
SELECT CONVERT(date,Column_Name) As Date FROM Table_Name
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you for all answers.

what i really need is year. sorry for the misleading question.

the correct query for that is:

```
select distinct YEAR(created_on) as years from contacts
```

thank you