# How to extract information from table to populate a CALENDAR table in a created data warehouse

Tags: mysql, sql, database, extract, data-warehouse

I have a transaction table with an important column labeled `TDate`.

I need to use this column information to create a `Calendar` table. 
`TDate` Example: `2013-1-1`
In the `Calendar Table`, I must have `Month`, `Day`, `Year`  in different columns. 
What is a syntax to do so?

Comment: You are looking for [`year()`, `month()` and `day()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html). With these you can extract the respective portion of a date.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Get date from table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21978278/sql-get-date-from-table)

Comment: Wouldn't a 'calendar' table simply have all conceivable dates?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I think you are looking for it. Its just a simple use the YEAR, MONTH, DAY function to extract all these values and insert into different table as below.

```
create table test_2(TDate date);
insert into test_2 values(now());
select * from test_2;
create table calendar(year int, month int, day int);
insert into calendar select year(tdate) as year,month(tdate) as month, day(tdate) as day from test_2;

    mysql> select * from calendar;
    +------+-------+------+
    | year | month | day  |
    +------+-------+------+
    | 2018 |     5 |    5 |
    +------+-------+------+
    1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```